# Foreach loop not getting completed

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, for-loop, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Node js, nodemailer and firebase functions in my application.

I've a list of emails in an array `emailConfig`

```
const emailConfig = [
  {
    "name": "A",
    "Email": "A@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "Email": "B@gmail.com"
  }
];
```

So I need to send an email to all in `emailConfig`.

So I'm doing this,

```
function sendMail() {
  emailConfig.forEach(email => {
    const mailOptions = {
      from: 'abc@gmail.com',
      to: email.Email,
      subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
      text: `That was easy! ${email.name}`,
      attachments: [
        {
          filename: `${email.name}_KeyMetrics.xlsx`,
          path: `${tempath}/${email.name}_KeyMetrics.xlsx`
        },
        {
          filename: `${email.name}_MandatoryCourses.xlsx`,
          path: `${tempath}/${email.name}_MandatoryCourses.xlsx`
        },
      ]
    };
    return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (erro, info) => {
      if (erro) {
        return res.send(erro.toString());
      }
      return res.send('Sended');
    });
  });
}
```

I'm calling the `sendMail()` on request.

Issue is, I'm getting multiple emails and finally error in terminal `Error: Function timed out.`

sendMail() is not getting finished. What i'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: in your code snippet you are referring to a variable not defined in it. provide more details about `res`

Answer (score 2):

1. you cannot call `send()` after its first call on the single response (assuming your `res` is a `Response` socket).
2. `Array.forEach` is synchronous, your callbacks will no be handled properly.

Answer (score -1):

Function in `forEach` is does not return any result. So since you call `return` keyword, your thread stop at there. Try to remove return keyword like this:

```
function sendMail() {
  emailConfig.forEach(email => {
    const mailOptions = {
      from: 'abc@gmail.com',
      to: email.Email,
      subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
      text: `That was easy! ${email.name}`,
      attachments: [
        {
          filename: `${email.name}_KeyMetrics.xlsx`,
          path: `${tempath}/${email.name}_KeyMetrics.xlsx`
        },
        {
          filename: `${email.name}_MandatoryCourses.xlsx`,
          path: `${tempath}/${email.name}_MandatoryCourses.xlsx`
        },
      ]
    };
    //remove return below
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (erro, info) => {
      if (erro) {
        return res.send(erro.toString());
      }
      return res.send('Sended');
    });
  });
}
```

Or if you need an array of result. Try `.map()` prototype instead:

```
function sendMail() {
  emailConfig.map(email => { //replace forEach by map
    const mailOptions = {
      from: 'abc@gmail.com',
      to: email.Email,
      subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
      text: `That was easy! ${email.name}`,
      attachments: [
        {
          filename: `${email.name}_KeyMetrics.xlsx`,
          path: `${tempath}/${email.name}_KeyMetrics.xlsx`
        },
        {
          filename: `${email.name}_MandatoryCourses.xlsx`,
          path: `${tempath}/${email.name}_MandatoryCourses.xlsx`
        },
      ]
    };
    return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (erro, info) => {
      if (erro) {
        return res.send(erro.toString());
      }
      return res.send('Sended');
    });
  });
}
```